# How many active QGIS users are there in total?

Tags: qgis

I'm the CEO of [MangoMap](http://www.mangomap.com) which is a online GIS data management and web map publication platform, we're big QGIS fans and make extensive use of it. We would really love to integrate MangoMap more tightly with QGIS by making the transfer of data and edits completely seamless between the desktop projects in QGIS and MangoMap data/maps in the cloud. We already allow QGIS to get layers from MangoMap using WMS but want to make it much easier to send data and edits from QGIS to MangoMap.

Before we get started though I would really like to know if there are any up to date numbers out there on how many active QGIS users there are at this time. I've seen an article on [Spatial Galaxy](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/19/qgis-users-around-the-world/) from 2011 that estimated 100k, but it's my feeling that QGIS has matured and gained a lot of traction since then so the figure is unlikely still valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no official numbers, and I doubt there ever will be, as it is hard to count something that doesn't require registration or a licence.  Tracking IPs that have accessed the plugin repository is one way however proxies and other setups can make this only as good as a guess.

We can use the number of standalone windows downloads, however we can't trace linux or mac downloads.  The windows installer logs are [here](http://www.qgis.org/cgi-bin/awstats.pl?urlfilter=/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-1.8.0-.%2a-Setup.exe&urlfilterex=&output=urldetail&config=qgis&framename=mainright&month=all&year=2013). Be warned that is isn't a download and install count, and you can have bots etc also hitting the download links.

I would say 200K+ is a good number but without having a way to collect it we will never know.

**Note**: We have considered some kind of free optional registration just to collect number however it: doesn't sit well with a lot of people, myself included; feels cheap; not everyone will register; they aren't going to register if they don't get anything out of it and what can we give them anyway.

Comment: a lot of us only use nightly builds too and i do that on three platforms

Comment: This is very interesting information. Especially in the context of rivalry between QGIS and ArcGIS.

Comment: Although the original question is already a bit old, if someone stumbles across this question, I wrote a blog post where I try to estimate the number of users based on different metrics: https://www.gispo.fi/en/blog/how-big-is-the-qgis-community/